# Angular 7 Hangs on Redirect

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, ngrx

I'm trying to implement a Logout Component in Angular, but when i access /auth/logout on Chrome just hangs and on Firefox i'm getting a "A web page is slowing down your browser", like there was a for(;;) running.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.subscription = this.state.subscribe((state: any) => {
       if (isEmpty(state.auth) || state.auth.isAuthenticated === false) {
         this.router.navigate(['/']);
       }
   });
   this.authService.logout();
}
```

Has anyone ever had this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you have a circular route configured. Please provide your router config.

Comment: I just want to go to the root of the App. With window.location.href = '/' i get a 304 Not Modified

Comment: When is `this.authService.logout();` supposed to be called? In your current code it's always called before `this.state.subscribe...` is processed. That could actually be the main problem here.

Comment: @Lynx242 it's Ngrx, i call the Reducer and then it will callback when the logout actions have been performed

Comment: I just found a solution. Just put the this.router.navigate inside the effects.ts

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution.

I've put the `this.router.navigateByUrl('/')` inside the effects.ts . Working now!